# How to access Gradle `project` from `buildSrc`?

Tags: gradle

I have the following in `buildSrc`:

```
class MyClass {
    def doSomething() {
        final familyMembers = project.configurations['compile'].allDependencies.collect { dep ->
            dep.name
        }
    }
```

but when I try to use it in `build.gradle`:

```
task 'do-something' << {
    final myObject = new MyClass()
    myObject.doSomething()
}
```

the following error is emitted:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':my-project:do-something'.
> No such property: project for class: MyClass
```

How do I get `project` to be visible within `MyClass`?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to pass project as a parameter to MyClass.

For example, declare a constructor and a member variable:

```kotlin
    class MyClass {
        private Project project

        MyClass(Project project) {
          this.project = project
        }

        def doSomething() {
            final familyMembers = project.configurations['compile'].allDependencies.collect { dep ->
                dep.name
            }
        }
```

and then use it from your project as such:

```
    task 'do-something' << {
        final myObject = new MyClass(project)
        myObject.doSomething()
    }
```

Comment: Either that, or write a plugin or task class, both of which have access to `project`.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser - I agree, if class nicely "fits" into new role (plugin or task), it should be converted to it.